# MySQL 5.1 Is not enforcing FK constraint, when i delete a row from the parent,

Tags: mysql

MYSQL 5.1 : 2 tables (parent , child); FK in child links to primary of Parent.

When i go to the mysql command line and do a delete on the parent. 
It is allowing me to delete.

When i same test on  on MySQL 5.6. i get the error "Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails" which I expect.

How could this be possible ? How come MySQL is not enforcing my foreign key constraint ?

One other point both these tables are part of a replication setup. both these tables are replicated to similar space on another db server on different box..

Comment: Delete the children depending on the parent before deleting it.

Comment: Show us the `create table` statement you used. Also check the (default) storage engine in your 5.1 installation. That might still be MyISAM which doesn't support FKs

Comment: CONSTRAINT `blahblah` FOREIGN KEY (`blah`) REFERENCES `moreblah` (`moreblah_id`)) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to set your foreign key to `ON DELETE CASCADE`. This means that deleting the parent forces the child to delete itself. The error your getting is because the foreign key stops the parent deleting itself because the child cannot delete itself.

```
CONSTRAINT `child_table` 
    FOREIGN KEY (`parent_id`) 
    REFERENCES `parent_table` (`id`) 
    ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have the "on Delete CASCADE" option, Explicitly configured in the DB Schema.

Comment: Is there a way that mysql is implicitly by default selecting this option , through general configuration / or global paramaters ?

Comment: When ever you create your foreign key, you have to specify the type. Instead of set default, you use cascade. You will have to update your tables manually to reflect this.